# use xcom_pull to pull a key's value that same task pushed - Airflow

Tags: airflow

I've built an Airflow Operator that executes HTTP request against a cloud API.
After executing a request I get a `run_id` that identifies the execution, and then keep checking my request status until it finish (it can take some time).

I'm trying to develop a mechanism that will save this `run_id` to xCom, for cases of network issues/ spot taken, when my pod loose connection with the cloud service.
I'm using Airflow retries, so I want to resume the same connection after the failure and keep checking the status of the `run_id` that saved to xCom.

I was able to push the `run_id` to xCom, but I when I pull it for the same task I get `None` instead of the value that I pushed and see in the Admin dashboard (I could pull it for other tasks in the pipeline).

- Is there any limitation for getting xCom pushed value that was pushed from the same task (in earlier try) that I'm trying to pull from?
- I have also an option to use airflow Variables instead of xCom, but it looks like it's not relevant for my use-case but for sharing data between dags (and in my use case I want to share data between task to itself in future run).

I execute this code inside the `execute` function of my operator:
This is how I pushed the value:

```
self.xcom_push(context, key='run_id', value='111')
```

This is how I pulled the values:

```
value = self.xcom_pull(context, key='run_id', task_ids=self.task_id, include_prior_dates=True)
```

but value is always `None` (unless I try to pull data of other task (but it's not relevant for my use case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used airflow Variables instead of xCom, since it's not possible to get xCom pushed value that was pushed from the same task (in an earlier try).

Comment: "since it's not possible to get xCom pushed value that was pushed from the same task" did you find this somewhere from the documentation? or this was your conclusion from trial and errors?

Comment: this was my conclusion, it's not clear in the documentation.
they only write:

XComs are a relative of Variables, with the main difference being that XComs are per-task-instance and designed for communication within a DAG run, while Variables are global and designed for overall configuration and value sharing.

Comment: I ended up using Variables too, you are right.. documentations did not mention this case and I burned way too much time figuring this out. Thanks!

Comment: Hi nofar, I face the same issue and would be delighted if you could share your working solutions. PS: you are right about xcoms, they only persist per try due to its idepotency. Persisting data between tries should be better incorporated in ariflow IMO.

Comment: @Bennimi hey, I was using: Variable.set(f'{id}_run_id', run_id) to set the value and  Variable.get(f'{{id}_run_id', None) to get the value. and imported Variable like this: from airflow.models import Variable

Comment: thanks nofar!! That was also the best solution that came to my mind.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that you have a folder shared between all workers, an alternative solution is using a file to store whatever you need to pass between task runs, including multiple runs of the same one.
This solution is a good replacement of XCOM overall, which is usually a more expensive operation (DB) than simple file operations. Just create a subfolder from your DAG run id and use that across all the task of your DAG.